# Create a connector: How to put an initial/default value in a field

Tags: looker-studio

I would like to set a default value in a field, but I don't find the function.

CONFIG

```
var myField = cc.newDimension() // Or newMetric
  .setId('my_unique_identifier')
  .setName('My friendly name')
  .setDescription('My short description')
  .setType(types.YEAR_MONTH_DAY)
  .setGroup('My group name');
```

Answer (score 1):

This currently is a missing feature. There isn't a built in way for having an initial/default value for a field.

The way to get around is to implement your own config validation method which will assign the default values if any of the values are missing/matches certain criteria. See example code [here](https://github.com/googledatastudio/community-connectors/blob/master/stackoverflow-questions/src/main.js#L325).

Comment: Hi @minhaz-kazi. I already used connectors that have default value. [link] (https://1drv.ms/u/s!AsVdASJKbH0Pg6NcpMmG3atME6aLTw)

Comment: I believe that's a placeholder (See example [here](https://developers.google.com/datastudio/connector/reference#getconfig)). Placeholders do not automatically get applied as default value.